# multilingual data from resource file

Tags: asp.net, localization, resources, multilingual, prerender

I have two resource file **Resource.resx** and **Resource.ar.resx** 
with the same keys but different **english** and **arabic** data 
in the following code the text in the  is working fine showing **english** and **arabic** data with the change in the dropdownlist while the text of the save button always shows English not arabic

```
       </tr>
            <tr>
        <td><span><%=Resources.Resource.Citations%></span></td>
        <td>
            <input runat="server" id="taCitations" type="number" style="width: 600px;" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="<%$Resources:Resource, Save%>" CssClass="btn" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
```

I have a dropdownlist in master page

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlLang" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
                                <asp:ListItem Text="English" Value="en-US">
                                <asp:ListItem Text="Arabic" Value="ar-sa" />
                            </asp:DropDownList>
```

and my work to change language is in preRender of the master page

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"] != null && Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"].Contains("ddlLang"))
    {
        //Set the Language.
        Language = Request.Form[Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"]];

    }
    if (Language == "en-US")
    {
        Body.Attributes["dir"] = "ltr";
        tdAppParticulars.Attributes["align"] = "right";

    }
    else
    {
        Body.Attributes["dir"] = "rtl";
        tdAppParticulars.Attributes["align"] = "left";

    }
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(Language);
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(Language);
    List<ExtFormInstruction1> lefi = bal.ExtFormInstructionByType("External Reviewers");

    formInstructions = new Hashtable();
    formIDs = new Hashtable();
    string currentItemURL = "";
    foreach (ExtFormInstruction1 row in lefi)
    {
        string itemURL = row.Page;
        formInstructions[row.Page] = Language == "ar-sa" ? "" : row.Instruction;
        formIDs[row.Page] = row.FormID;
        if (Language == "en-US")
        {
            lblPageTitle.Text = row.Title;
        }
        else if (Language == "ar-sa")
        {
            lblPageTitle.Text = bal.GetFormByPage(row.Page.Replace(".aspx", "Ar.aspx"))[0].Title;

        }
    }

    MakeMenu(Language);
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        return;
    }
    lblApplicantEmail.Text = bal.GetApplicant(ApplicationID)[0].NameString;
    lblEmployee.Text = erBAL.GetExtRevByID(ExtReviewerID)[0].Name;
    /* printer friendly */
    if (Utils.IsPrintMode())
    {
        tdLeftMenu.Visible = false;
        lnkPrint.Visible = false;
    }
    lnkPrint.NavigateUrl = currentItemURL + "?print=1";

}
```

the Language is a property in master page

```
public string Language
{
    set
    {
        Session["Language"] = value;
    }
    get
    {
        if (Session["Language"] != null)
        {
            return Session["Language"].ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            return "en-US";
        }
    }
}
```

[image][image]

[image: The resource files are added in the GlobalResources]

Comment: the issue is only with the `button` ?

Comment: yes Exactly!     <%$Resources:Resource, Save%> does not work with multilingual

Comment: Is there a chance that `Resource.ar.resx` doesn't have `Save` key or value ?? also, you might have misspelled key or resource files syntax ?

Comment: no not at all both the resource files have Same Save key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather do it like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" meta:resourceKey="SaveButton"  CssClass="btn" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
```

And in the Resource.resx file, the entries will be like

```
Name: SaveButton.Text
Value: Save
Name: SaveButton.Tooltip
Value: Click to Submit
```

Similarly in Resource.ar.resx file

```
Name: SaveButton.Text
Value: حفظ
Name: SaveButton.Tooltip
Value: انقر فوق لتقديم
```

Comment: It does not  work although I put the Resource.resx and Resource.ar.resx file in the App_LocalResources folder